# connection status using Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

i'm using MySQL Database with my c# application , and the database in server in locally.
In Each function in the application (Button click, etc.) i open the connection and in the end i close it, like this:

```
private void btn_addAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            **objConn.Open();**
                    //
                    MySqlCommand cmd;
                    if(from == "bill_Details")
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into accounts (acc_Name,acc_Person,acc_Number,acc_Place,acc_Date,cus_Sup) values ('" + txbName.Text + "','" + txbPerson.Text + "','" + txbNumber.Text + "','" + txbPlace.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "',"+ Bill_Details.cus_Sup +")", objConn);
                    else
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into accounts (acc_Name,acc_Person,acc_Number,acc_Place,acc_Date,cus_Sup) values ('" + txbName.Text + "','" + txbPerson.Text + "','" + txbNumber.Text + "','" + txbPlace.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "'," + Suppliers.cus_Sup + ")", objConn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


             **objConn.Close();**
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I felt in this way that the application need more time to open and close the connection !
is't right like that or i have to open the connection in the starting of application and close it when it close !?

Comment: No, you should always create, open, use, close and dispose the connection when you need it. Connection Pooling is the answer to your doubts (See [Table 7.2 here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html). And you should also learn how to use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). (for example, if you get an exception in the code above, you have forgot to close the connection)

Comment: but in this way , does it take more time ?